# Replace few XML tags values using sed.exe in windows batch command

Tags: xml, windows, sed

I need to replace values in a file using sed in windows batch command. here is the structure:

```
<Prop id="123" name="@REPR:Reference">
    <value>%runtime_variable%</value>
</Prop>
```

I want to replace the value into below format:

```
<Prop id="123" name="@REPR:Reference">
    <value>%another_variable%</value>
</Prop>
```

I tried this command:

`C:\workspace\development\tools\cygwin\bin>sed -i -r 's/<Prop id="123" name="@REPR:Reference">\<value>.*</value>\</Prop>\/<Prop id="123" name="@REPR:Reference">\<value>%another_variable%</value>\</Prop>\/g' /cygdrive/c/Users/xyz/input.xml`

But it is not working. I get this error:

> The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Are you using cygwin? If not, you can't use single quotes to quote arguments.

Comment: Also, `\<` has special meaning in sed.

Comment: Yes I'm using cygwin. I edited my question.

Comment: `sed` isn't exactly the most appropriate tool for modifying XML, which isn't a regular language. Are you married to Cygwin or could you also use PowerShell, which has much better ways of editing XML?

Comment: The suggestion is to use sed.exe. But, I can use sh.exe if there is no other way.

Comment: `sh` is the Unix shell. PowerShell is the shell built into (recent versions of) Windows that can do much of what you would otherwise do with Cygwin and related ports of Unix tools. What you want can, of course, be done with `sed` if you just pound on it hard enough, but as a way of moving forward with batch files on Windows PowerShell is a better investment.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I will use PowerShell.